# Display child DIVs one by one in Parent DIV after regular intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have following requirement. I have many divs in one div. I want to display one div at a time for 30 seconds and the next div and so on..

```
<div id="Parent">

    <div id="Child1">
     I am DIV 1
    </div>

    <div id="Child2">
     I am DIV 2
    </div>

    <div id="Child3">
     I am DIV 3
    </div>

</div>
```

How is it possible with ajax and jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 (function () {
   $('#Parent div').hide().first().show();
   setInterval(function () {
    $('#Parent div:first').hide().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo("#Parent");
   }, 3000);

})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F98zF/12/

change 3000 to 30000 (3 sec to 30 sec) in your code

Answer (score 2):

It depends if the content of `div` does not change then I would do it using `jQuery` but if content could be changed then we should get them by `ajax`.

Bringing static contents with ajax on each iteration is useless and will consume extra resources of machine and bandwidth. You can use use `setInterval` to show divs one after other and It will be used if you bring or do not bring the contents with ajax.

Comment: I have asked a simple question but my requirement is complex. Yes, the contents of divs will change.

Comment: Does the content change during it iteration?

Comment: contents are static of each div

Comment: Then you probably do not need ajax.